# Unable to open Activity for ACTION_APP_LOCALE_SETTINGS

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm trying to open new App locale settings screen introduced in Tiramisu (Android 13 - Api33)

I'm using current emulator (REVISION 6) of Androd 13, and with that when trying to open it with

```
override fun openAppLocaleSettings(activity: Activity) {
        activity.startActivity(
            Intent(Settings.ACTION_APP_LOCALE_SETTINGS, Uri.parse(context.packageName))
        )
    }
```

I'm getting

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.settings.APP_LOCALE_SETTINGS dat= }
```

Is there something wrong with above code, or maybe it is not implemented yet by Android?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was missing `package` scheme for uri, e.x. it should be `package:your.package.name`

```
activity.startActivity(
            Intent(Settings.ACTION_APP_LOCALE_SETTINGS, Uri.parse("package:your_package_name"))
        )
```

Comment: Maybe this would be more expressive: `activity.startActivity(
                    Intent(Settings.ACTION_APP_LOCALE_SETTINGS, Uri.parse("package:${context.packageName}")))
`